# How to Automate text entries in Java script pop up

Tags: javascript, selenium, automation

Is there any way through which I can automate the process of entering the user name and password in the Java script pop up.The browser i prefer is Firefox.

I tried send keys. `driver.switchTo().alert().sendKeys`. It isn't working either. Please help.

Comment: please share your web driver code with question.

Comment: WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.get("http://abc");
            driver.switchTo().alert().sendKeys("xxxx");

Comment: is that popup is iframe or child browse window??

Comment: I am not sure. I guess it is javascript alert. As i cannot access any element in the browser without addressing it.

Comment: please share that site URL where you are testing.

Comment: http://aus-gen2.tul.solarwinds.net/

Comment: This URL is not accessible, may be it's not public.. Please upload a screenshot of the pop up in [imgur](http://imgur.com/) and put here.

Comment: That URL is not opening.

Comment: I was not able to upload a picture, stack overflow is asking for atleast10 point reputation

Comment: Did you try for(String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
         driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);

Comment: yeah..Selenium is not considering the pop up as a window. I can get window handle of the main window but not the pop up.

Comment: @user3857726 - your given info. not enough to help you.

Comment: @HelpingHands: It is a OS level Authentication message